# How to get the Current document value with arrayElemAt in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a sample data

```
    instock:[ 
       { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, 
       { warehouse: "C" },
       { warehouse: "B",qty: 6 },
 ] }
```

in my case i have three arrays, i want to get the `instock.qty` for index 1 which is null, but am getting the value `6` instead of null. please let me know what am doing wrong here

this is the query which i have written

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { $project: { 

      qty: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$instock.qty", 1] }

      } }    
]);
```

As of my understanding there is no `qty` field in index `1` so it is skipping the index `1` and going to index `2`. how to over come this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `.dot` syntax with an array operator gives you the array of elements. You can check it [**here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A6ea_Mo3Dln) and thus you are getting second first element as `6`.

So instead you can find the 1st array element then can use `.dot` syntax

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "qty": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$instock", 1] }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "qty": {
      "$ifNull": ["$qty.qty", null]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CffAfMeH0GF)

Comment: this is good, only if i know the index 1 is not having the qty field, how can i do this dynamically with array missing with qty field, will this work

Comment: You can use `$filter` aggregation. https://mongoplayground.net/p/PQrKJVRSzuP